# Check is a Self-Hosted-Service is running or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Self-Hosted-Service(using WCF) that will run on clients machines. That service is supposed to make request to another server, get the data as XML then it returns to me that data as `JSONP`. Now i want to check if the service is running or not .. How can i check that ?

In my JS code i use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with callback, so i tried to use `.fail` like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/url?callback=?", function () {
    alert("success");
}).fail(function () {
    alert('fail');
})
```

but fail function didn't called when the server is not running(on chrome the Type is `pending` and `Status` is Failed)

Then i tried to use $.AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/url?callback=?',
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('request successful');
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('request failed');
    }
});
```

I got the same result.

Comment: localhost is not a remote machine, are you sure you have disabled port 8080 on localhost, just to start with the simplest thing I can imagine.. replace `localhost` by `djq3oilkthoi3thjst`

Comment: my localhost service makes calls to other/remote servers, then return to me the result as JSON

Answer (score 0):

When you make the AJAX request to your localhost and `/url?` returns weather the *other* server is up or not, your script won't fail. Because `http://localhost/url` is online.

I'd make the `/url` script return JSON array with `remoteHostOnline: true or false`, 
then use:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: 'http://localhost:8080/url?callback=?',
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    if (data.remoteHostOnline == false) {
        alert('remote host not online');
    }
}
});
```

You might have to tweak this script I didn't test it but you will understand what's wrong.

Comment: the problem is that if the localhost service not running then the request failed but the callback for error does not get fired